# check current directory listing when system is ran out of process table?

Tags: linux

that simple..but how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll be limited to shell built-ins, so if you're running `bash`, type `help` and examine the built-ins available.

For example, you should be able to do

```
$ echo *
```

to list the filenames in the current directory.

Assuming you want to try and recover the system after looking at the current directory, there are a number of options available to you.

Importantly, `kill(1)` is built-in, so you can use that to free up process slots.

You can navigate /proc to examine the running processes - `/proc/<pid>/cmdline` will contain the process names which you can read directly in the shell:

```
$ read line < /proc/self/cmdline
$ echo $line
```

That may help find which process IDs you need to kill.

Answer (score 1):

You mean you've run out of available PID's?

Most shells list the current directory with a built-in, rather than by invoking the ls binary so you shouldn't expend a pid.

That said I'd probably just kill 100 or so pids at random to give myself some breathing room with which to fix whatever went wrong.

Comment: But we can't add a new process at all. Do you know if we can fork from shell? If we can, then we should be able to run the code under a thread instead of a process.